# Flashbots with 0 gasPrice

Tags: flashbots, relay

When I simulate the transaction I want to send a 0x data and the gasPrice seems 0 thus I am not included any one has any idea why the gasPrice is 0. How can I increase the gasPrice

```
{
   "results": [
      {
         "txHash": "0x5a9188c7dfaecbffa298e8a085c621f09fbaa0346b6bc67679ad3d69d9431ada",
         "gasUsed": 21000,
         "gasPrice": "0",
         "gasFees": "0",
         "fromAddress": "from",
         "toAddress": "to",
         "coinbaseDiff": "0",
         "ethSentToCoinbase": "0",
         "value": "0x"
      },
      {
         "txHash": "0x3c9b44a2b0e71b98352e35a67a7138db01a9c849b782ad69a830552d83aa5fdb",
         "gasUsed": 21000,
         "gasPrice": "0",
         "gasFees": "0",
         "fromAddress": "from",
         "toAddress": "to",
         "coinbaseDiff": "0",
         "ethSentToCoinbase": "0",
         "value": "0x"
      }
   ],
   "coinbaseDiff": "17948700000000",
   "gasFees": "17948700000000",
   "ethSentToCoinbase": "0",
   "bundleGasPrice": "81037261",
   "totalGasUsed": 221487,
   "stateBlockNumber": 18078793,
   "bundleHash": "0x6d900009f1209e4c765c2e13872c6eaed18cb1226070a113f8c1794b9cbb8b7c"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how you are setting the gas in your request.
For a single private transaction, should probably be setting it in the message before signing, an example could be:

```py
tx = { 'data': SIG, 'to': WASTE_GAS, 'from': EOA,'value':0,'chainId': 5,'gas': 50000,'maxFeePerGas': w3.to_wei('60', 'gwei'), 'maxPriorityFeePerGas': w3.to_wei('20', 'gwei'),'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(EOA)}
```

There may also be a minimum to be included

> // Flashbots currently enforces a gas used floor. As of August 2021, that value is 42,000 gas. Any transaction that consumes less than this floor is rejected by relay
> // This contract enables testing Flashbots with a single, simple transaction that will consume transaction's gas limit, ensuring the bundle won't be rejected
> // See: https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/advanced/bundle-pricing

The link no longer seems to show this or could be for bundle only, but people will call a gas wasting contract when testing.

Here are some if needed on Goerli:

```py
WASTE_GAS = '0x8e63F02d5fB3bCCD2939e0ba6Fe3Bf2635718F49'
SIG = '0x1e0bd6fa'
# consumes 43674 and has callable sig
```

```py
wasteGas = '0x957B500673A4919C9394349E6bbD1A66Dc7E5939'
# consumes gas limit through fallback
```

Comment: const firstTx = {
    to: "to_address",
    from: searcherWallet.address,
    data: "0x",
    chainId: 1,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: 0,
    maxFeePerGas: nextBaseFee,
    gasLimit: 250000,
    nonce: nonce + 1,
    type: 2,
  };

I send this tx twice. I will try your method but after checking my tx if you have any other suggestions please let me know

Comment: I don't use js but I think you have getFeeData() in ethersjs to get gas fees. Try filling your fields with competitive fees. Mainnet is currently about 10 gwei base fee, 1-2 gwei priority fee. For max fee use both those added together.